# What skills do I need to land a job in python domain?

Tags: careers, career-switch

I am a seasoned **java developer** with 8 years experience. I want to get into **python domain mainly web**. What skills should I focus. Also does prior experience matters in python domain that much or I can showcase the projects I have created in python

Comment: Python would be a useful skill to have

Comment: "Also does prior experience matters in python domain that much" Why would I hire someone with no experience in python when I have 5 applicants that have 10 years of experience in python and 95 others with 1-2 years of experience in python? I think the answer to this question is self-explanatory.

Comment: @james I agree I have no experience in python, but my point was can self made projects and other things help in this

Comment: If you want to use Python, look for companies that use Python for web development and send them your resume. A lot of companies would hire an experienced web developer with no prior knowledge of Python, since it's a technology that someone with enough experience should be able to pick up relatively quickly.

Comment: @amol Of course. If you can translate your experience in Java to writing a project in Python then by all means you should be showcasing this. Backing up your experience with tangible evidence is never a bad idea.

Comment: @James
When was the last time you had 5 applicants with 10 years of experience?

Comment: @Helena Yesterday. We posted a job that received 362 applications in 6 hours and a fraction of those claimed 10 or more years of experience.

Comment: Python isn't a domain; it's a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with every other job, go look at job ads and see what they want. This can change from year to year, country to country, region to region.

Apart from the obvious answer: [python](/questions/tagged/python), there will be more skills and they will not be hidden. They will be advertised. Look at the job ads of the jobs you *want* and then go from there.

Answer (score 3):

Other than the obvious, the answer here is "marketing". You need to convince me, the hiring manager, why it would be a better idea for me to hire you, a Java developer with no professional Python experience, than any of the other people I get CVs for, all of whom have Python experience. What skills can you bring to my company that those folk don't have to make up for the fact that you *are* going to be slower to get up to speed and productively contributing to my company?

If you can't answer that question, you're always going to be somewhere towards the bottom of the list of potential candidates, so you need to make sure that both your CV and any conversations your have with recruiters, hiring managers or anyone else highlight how your skills and experience are going to bring benefits.